# Calling all comments for certain posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with a Rails 2.3.9 application and in this case posts are `workouts`. I am trying to get all `comments` for the following `workouts`.

```
@workouts = Workout.today_only.all(:include => {:user => :memberships}, :conditions => ["workouts.public = '1' AND memberships.box_id = ?", @box.id], :order => "workouts.created_at DESC")
```

My associations are correct:

```
Workout has_many :comments
Comment belongs_to :workout
```

How would I get at list of comments on those specifc workouts ordered by `created_at DESC`?

Note: `today_only` is a named_scope and I can post the code if it is relevant.

Comment: I'd recommend creating more named_scopes for those conditions and includes. Right now your code has several levels of abstraction on the same line.

Comment: Yea I agree. Just need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your Workout model, add:

```
has_many :comments, :order => 'created_at DESC'
```

then you can do:

```
Workout.today_only.all(:include => [:comments, {:user => :memberships}], ...
```

Comment: What is the view code after that? Ideally I want to display all the comments in one stream. As opposed to going to get each workout and then displaying the comments for each workout.

Comment: You can: @comments = Comment.all(["workout_id IN ?", @workouts]) -- but I'd put that SQL into a class method on Comment.